# Getting Discord html with python?

Tags: python

I'm trying to get the html from https://discord.com/channels/@me the problem i'm running into is that there has to be some kind of login procedure that i can't figure out how to do with requests. the only information i have to login is the token(my friend doesn't trust me with his login info), so I can't just login with the user and pass, I've attempted to figure out if i can change local storage of the site so i can put in the token but to no avail, any ideas?

Comment: What's the reason for needing the HTML? Why not use any one of the vast number of APIs that Discord publishes...? What exactly is the "*token*" you mentioned?

Comment: If you need to just access the site make an account, if your friend is going to use this let the user enter the username + password at the start and create an account for testing. Also, consider using one of many Discord APIs or maybe [Selenium](https://pypi.org/project/selenium/) for Web Automatisation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The token you want to use to log into discord might have a time validity. (that's the token security) for example, you can use it for 1 hour an not after.
The easiest way to log you on discord would be to use Selenium in order to automate tasks of your browser.